SqlException when using instance in SQL Server connection string
Currently I am using .NET 8 and AddDbContext with UseSqlServer:
 services.AddDbContext<DbContext>((provider, options) =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(dbConnectionString);
            });

When the app is deployed to a linux environment, this error occurs:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

The instance part \i01 seems to be causing the issue in the connection string:
Data Source=<DB_ALIAS>\i01,99999;Initial Catalog=DbName;User ID=<username>;Password=<password>

Did Microsoft change something recently or am I providing an invalid connection string?

You shouldn't use both port and instancename, so i'm pretty sure the answer to your quesiton is the second one

The instance name is ignored when the a port number is specified.  Data Source=YourServer,99999 should work but the error message the server/port cannot be reached. Test network connectivity.

Sounds plausible, but why does the above connection string work on a local Windows environment? The error occurs only on a Linux machine. In addition, previosly when using .NET 6 the connectionstring didn't raise any errors.

99999 is a rather unusual port number ... is that an obfuscated number or your actual port?

Port is a placeholder -> obfuscated.

Finally found a topic on Github: https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/2378
Seems to be the same issue.

In addition to the comments above, I have also seen issue in Visual Studio where I have had to escape the "" character. Try adding an additional slash before it (i.e., \io1)

Have you tested port connectivity?

It's working without instance and only a port. Does Microsoft (Sql Server) provide documentation about using port and instance? Is instance always irrelevant when the connectionstring contains a port?

Have you opened SQL Browser port in the firewall? It's 1434 i think. It might only be opened to domain traffic which stops your linux stuff. Personally, i'd never use the instance name stuff

If you provide a port  do NOT use instancename

If you know the port then don't bother using the instance name. Instance name resolution adds fragility and latency to your connection setups: it requires that the client perform an SSRP (SQL Server Resolution Protocol) request to the SQL Browser service listening on the target server's udp/1434 port, resolve the instance name to the TCP socket that the instance is listening on, and return that port number to the client for it then to connect on.

Use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to the database.  Check in login window if you are using Windows Credential or SQL Credential.  Then check log file which is in the explorer under Management.  There should be a login with a user/group for each attempted connection with c#.  See if there are any errors.
